# UIImagePickerViewController Freezes in iOS

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, static-libraries

I am using static librrary and there is one class inside it that uses `UIImagePickerViewController`. I have set the delegate to it and written `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`: method within that class. What I want is to open front camera, capture the image when user clicks it and then save it to Photo Albums. What is happening with my code is that `UIImagePickerController` loads the camera and it saves the photo after capturing when I click on "Use Photo" button. But after that, it freezes but not crashes. I can't click anywhere after that. Any help appreciated. Thanks

// CODE IN LIBRARY

```
+ (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage* photo = (UIImage*) [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(photo);

    photo = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data].CGImage
                                   scale:photo.scale
                             orientation:photo.imageOrientation];

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(photo, self, nil, nil);

    // TRIED ALL OF THE BELOW BUT NOTHING WORKS FOR ME

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    // [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [picker.view.superview removeFromSuperview];
    //    [picker release];
    //    picker=nil;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some piece of code ?

Comment: @delannoyk - Added code for you

Comment: Why is it a static method ??

Answer (score 0):

Your method shouldn't be static - remove the '+' and replace it with '-'.

Also, in the method you do

```
[picker.view.superview removeFromSuperview];
```

I'm not sure that's what you want to do !

So your code becomes :

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    ...
}
```